# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'feature_names'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

%matplotlib inline

boston = load_boston()
print(boston.keys())
```

When I type this I get the output:
`dict_keys(['data', 'target', 'feature_names', 'DESCR', 'filename'])`
so I know that feature_names is an attribute. However, when I type

```
boston.columns = boston.feature_names
```

the ouput comes as
`'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'feature_names'`

Comment: try ```boston['feature_names']```

Comment: By the looks of the input , boston is a sklearn.utils.Bunch , try and create the df using `df = pd.DataFrame(boston.data,columns=boston.feature_names)`

Comment: Type in ```boston.columns.values``` to see an array of your column names

Comment: @DavidMeu ah it still says KeyError: 'feature_names'

Comment: @anky when I try that I get the ouput `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'data'`

Comment: @chiggywiggy when i run your code I dont get boston as a dataframe. Are you sure the code you are running is exactly same as your question?

Comment: @DavidMeu The column names are simply numbered and I'm trying to change them to the feature_names

Comment: @chiggywiggy you code doesn't give the error you posted.

Comment: @anky yes, I ran `boston = pd.DataFrame(boston.data)`  didn't show it

Comment: @chiggywiggy exactly. Dont do it. Try using only the code you showed and then use the code I gave you in comments

Comment: @anky it worked! thank you

Comment: @chiggywiggy Welcome. Always include the full code so we can understand where you went wrong , thank you and Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 3):

To convert boston *sklearn* dataset to pandas Dataframe use:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(boston.data,columns=boston.feature_names)
df['target'] = pd.Series(boston.target)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar. Also with scikitlearn to make a random forest with this tutorial:
https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/random-forests-classifier-python

I stumbled upon this line of code:

```
import pandas as pd
feature_imp = pd.Series(clf.feature_importances_,**index=iris.feature_names**).sort_values(ascending=False)
feature_imp
```

I got an error from the bold part (between the **).
Thanks to the suggestions of #anky and #David Meu I tried:

```
feature_imp = pd.Series(clf.feature_importances_, index = dfNAN.columns.values).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

that results in the error:

```
ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (5)
```

so I tried:

```
feature_imp = pd.Series(clf.feature_importances_, index = dfNAN.columns.values[:4]).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

which works!