# Removing selected features from dataset

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am following this program: https://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/inspection/plot_permutation_importance_multicollinear.html

since I have a problem with highly correlated features in my model (different from that one shown in the example). In this step

```
selected_features = [v[0] for v in cluster_id_to_feature_ids.values()]
```

I can get information on the features that I will need to remove from my classifier. They are given as numbers (`[0, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 17]`). How can I get names of these features?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there are two different elements to this problem I think.

First, you need to get a list of the column names. In the example code you linked, it looks like the list of feature names is stored like this:

```py
data.feature_names
```

Once you have the feature names, you'd need a way to loop through them and grab only the ones you want. Something like this should work:

```py
columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
keep_index = [0, 3]

new_columns = [columns[i] for i in keep_index]
new_columns
```

> ['a', 'b']

Comment: Thanks, Tyler Rosacker. With my data (that looks like those ones in the example, but they have one column for Tweets), I get this error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'feature_names'`. Do you know how I can handle? Printing: print(orig_df.keys()) I get the list of my columns. I have been following this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66657420/dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-feature-names

Comment: It sounds like you've got a pandas `DataFrame` instead of the way scikit [stores its data](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_boston.html)?

In that case the attribute would be `.columns` instead of `.feature_names`.